# in R: How do you sort a matrix by rowname index?

Tags: r, sorting

I have merged two matrices:

```
library(plyr)
df3 = as.data.frame(t(combn(4,3)))    
df4 = as.data.frame(t(combn(4,4)))    
t(rbind.fill(df3,df4))
```

I've done transposing mainly for my benefit so I can see what I'm doing.

I would like to output:

```
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]
V1    1    1    1    NA    1
V2    2    2    NA    2    2
V3    3   NA    3     3    3
V4   NA    4    4     4    4
```

I've tried various ways of matching/sorting/ordering but have got erroneous results. Any advice is welcome - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plyr); ## for rbind.fill()
df3 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(4,3)));
df4 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(4,4)));
df <- t(rbind.fill(df3,df4));
apply(df,2L,function(col) col[match(seq_along(col),col)]);
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    1    1   NA    1
## [2,]    2    2   NA    2    2
## [3,]    3   NA    3    3    3
## [4,]   NA    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: On closer inspection, this is incorrect. Needs to match by row. I've tried match along(row) and it still doesn't work....what do you suggest?

Comment: the fourth row should have "4", not "3"?

Comment: The fourth row *does* have 4.

Comment: I refreshed and they changed to 4. It was originally showing:
[4,]   NA    3    3    3    4 ..... sorry about that. Thanks!